# Creating a task for 1 second

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to configure a crontab task that every second loads me a '.php' file in another server. That means from server1 I call a file in server2.

So server1 do a crontab tast like `0 * * * * wget http://server2.com/file.php`

file2, a php file, has a `while(true){//tasks; sleep(1)}`

My question is if this is the best way to do what I want and in case that isn't the best, tell me the right one

Thanks in advice!

P.D: I haven't any knowledge in shell programming.

Comment: I think the question is more why do you want to be pinging server2 every second?

Comment: I thought cron only worked down to minutes, not to seconds

Comment: You're doing the same thing twice. Calling file.php once will have it execute //tasks every second, so why call it every second too? You'll end up with multiple instances stacking up as that script will never quit.

Comment: What is it in specific what you are trying to do (i.e. what is the goal), because you are doing it wrong

Comment: What he's doing is calling the script every hour, and from there the script runs the task every second. I believe that pretty much is the only way to do it, as cron is limited to min. Just make sure u kill the script before you start it again.

Comment: I'm trying to update a database in server1 from server2 to have the info updated constantly. That's why 1 second

Comment: Database replication is your friend

Comment: Don't use cron for this, use database replication: most databases provide a built-in mechanism that is a lot more efficient than anything you could write yourself in PHP

Comment: What DB are you running? Postgres, Mysql...?

Comment: I already have a cassandra database with NoSQL, so it's not my point at all to replicate. It does by itself. My point is that I'm personally studying bash and I'm trying to improve this hypotetical way. So I was expecting a cron calling an sh file sleeping 1 second and executing a task that calls a php file or something like that

Comment: Its just not a smart way to do it, You could end up with multiple instances running and end up putting the server under unnecessary load. I really suggest u use what was made by the db devs.